# session_start() No funciona

Tags: php

Tengo un problema un poco raro...
Tengo un formulario en una hoja llamada **navbar.php*

El formulario envía por método **$POST** los datos a otro archivo **login_verificar.php** (En el que estoy haciendo pruebas y) que tiene lo siguiente:

```
<div class='dropdown-menu '  id='formulario_login'>

                <form action='/area_login/login_verificar.php' method='POST' class='col'>
                    <div class='form-group class=''  ' >
                        <label for='exampleInputEmail1'>Nombre de Usuario</label>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control'  name='username'  >
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for='exampleInputEmail1'>Contraseña</label>
                        <input type='password' class='form-control'  name='password'  >
                    </div>
                        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary ' id='Botonformulario' name='login'>Enviar</button>
                        <div class='dropdown-divider'></div>
                        <a class='dropdown-item' href='/area_login/pagina_recuperar_usuario.php'>¿Olvidaste tu usuario?</a>
                        <a class='dropdown-item' href='/area_login/pagina_recuperar_contraseña.php'>¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
                        <a class='dropdown-item' href='/area_login/pagina_crear_cuentas.php' >¿Crear una cuenta?</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </li>"; } else{

            
            
              if (isset($_SESSION['nombre'])){ echo 
              "<li class='nav-item dropdown' id='usuario'>
                 <a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' id='usuario'  href='#' role='button' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>
                 ⬤ $_SESSION[nombre] </a>
                 <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='navbarDropdown'>
                 <a class='dropdown-item' href='/area_login/login_salir.php'>Cerrar sesion</a>
                 </div>


<?php

$usuario    = $_POST['username'];

$usuario =addslashes($usuario);
$usuario =strip_tags($usuario);


$contrasena = $_POST['password'];

$contrasena =addslashes($contrasena);
$contrasena =strip_tags($contrasena);


if($usuario =="admin" && $contrasena =="1234"){
     
session_start();
   $_SESSION['nombre']= 'Hola';
   $_SESSION['nivel']= '1';
    header("Location:../index.php");
}else{

        header("Location:/area_login/pagina_iniciar_sesion.php?error");
    
}

?>
```

Si te fijas el header **REENVIA** (SUPUESTAMENTE) la; **"session_start(), la SESSION 'nombre y la SESSION 'nivel**'" al **index.php** (El cual con un include mando llamar la **navbar.php** que es donde esta este mismo formulario que pongo al principio...)

Menciono que supuestamente lo hace porque **es como si la función session_start() no se enviara por el header Location:index.php** porque cuando pongo el **session_start()** directo en el index pues si que me inicia sesion y se LOGUEA pero el problema es que la sesión no me permite cerrar con **session_destroy** (El cual tengo en otro archivo);

```
<?php   
    unset($_SESSION['nombre']);
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:/index.php");  
?>
```

Sucede que; si pongo el **session_start()** y luego el **session_destroy()** en el **index.php** si que puedo iniciar y cerrar sesión (Pero solo en el INDEX.PHP si cambio de pagina la sesión se cierra sola).

La pregunta es esta:

¿Alguien sabe porque no puedo enviar la **session_start** a través del header o si a caso tengo que poner **session_start** y **session_destroy** en todos los documentos?

Comment: Tu pregunta es algo confusa, quizá porque confusamente tienes organizado el código. ¿Por qué re-envías al mismo sitio inicial? No entiendo. ¿No deberías sentarte y analizar a conciencia cómo tienes organizado el código? *Quiero partir de aquí, luego ir aquí, hacer tal cosa y luego ir a aquí*. Explícanos eso de entrada y quizá podamos ayudarte a resolver el problema, saliendo además de la enorme confusión con que has concebido tu programa.

Comment: Alta ensalada tenes. Por qué no lees sobre `$_SESSION` [link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php) y sobre `$_POST` [link] (https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) para comprender como funcionan.

Comment: A. Cedano; De hecho mi programa esta super bien ordenado, quien no me dejó expresarme fue stackoverflow con su editor pero el punto es tan simple como esto:

El boton del formulario ENVIAR te envía al archivo php "login_verificar" (Ahí lo puse arriba) y de allá te reenvia de nuevo al index.php pero como que no se trae consigo la funcion session_start( ) Ese es el dilema; 

Se pierde en el camino. Pero si la pongo manual session_start() en el index.php, todo funciona correctamente salvo que no puedo cerrar sesion 

La pregunta es: Porque se pierde session_start() cuando pasa por header?

Comment: lectura recomendada: https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: @SAGEX: `session_start()` no pasa por header. Son dos cosas totalmente distintas. De entrada, `session_start()` debe ser la primera instrucción después de `<?php`. Leete los links que te pusimos y vas a poder resolver tu problema. Y si no, editas la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

session_start() es la primera linea de php, deberias usarla en cada pagina donde vas a hacer uso de la sesion.

Saludos